# Setting YARN queue in PySpark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

When creating a Spark context in PySpark, I typically use the following code:

```
conf = (SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client").setAppName(appname)
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "10g")
        .set("spark.executor.instances", "7")
        .set("spark.driver.memory", "5g")
        .set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled","true")
        .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true")
        .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors","5")
        )
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

However, this puts it in the default queue, which is almost always over capacity.  We have several less busy queues available, so my question is - how do I set my Spark context to use another queue?

Edit: To clarify - I'm looking to set the queue for interactive jobs (e.g., exploratory analysis in a Jupyter notebook), so I can't set the queue with spark-submit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use below argument in you spark-submit command.

```
--queue queue_name
```

You can set this property in your code. `spark.yarn.queue`

Hope this will help.

Thanks

Comment: What about when not using spark-submit?  I often do exploratory analysis in a Jupyter notebook, for example.

Comment: please set the mentioned property. I added after edit.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `spark.yarn.queue` rather than `queue`.

```
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().set("spark.yarn.queue", "your_queue_name")
sc
```

Comment: add some information why to use this yarn.spark queue and maybe a link to the documentation of it.

Comment: I was unable to find a reference to the `yarn.spark.queue` that you suggest. Instead, this worked for me: 
`SparkSession.builder.appName('myapp').config(conf=SparkConf().setAll([('spark.yarn.queue', 'root.myqueue')])).getOrCreate()`

Comment: Setting "spark.yarn.queue" to the queue name helped.